# Register on-prem db as Dataset in Azure ML Studio UI

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

how can I connect the new Azure Machine Learning Studio UI to an on-premise SQL DB via an on-premise data Gateway?

In the classic version, once the gateway was installed and registered the Import data module offered it as a dataset type. In the new UI however it doesn't seem to be available.

Answer (score 0):

I just got confirmation from the pm of AML, on-prem SQL is not supported in AML yet, but it's now on our plan with no ETA.

I will forward your feedback to product team as well.